# ajax post form makes page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a input type="file" and on change of that input i want a form to submit.

```
$(document).on("change", "#image-upload", function (e) {
   $.ajax({
       url: '/BlogPost/UploadHomeReport',
       type: 'POST',
       data: $('#upload-image-form').serialize(),
       success: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="~/BlogPost/UploadHomeReport" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-image-form">
    <input type="file" id="image-upload" name="file" />
    <input type="text" name="destinationId" id="destinationId" />
</form>
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadHomeReport(HttpPostedFileBase file, int destinationId)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedImages/" + destinationId + fileName));
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedImages/" + destinationId + fileName);
    return Json(path);
}
```

Everything works perfectly, but when it should return the JSON it redirects to a new page. Why doesn't it return the JSON instead of redirecting?

Comment: Try remove the `action` in the form

Comment: If i do that the file in UploadHomeReport actionmethod becomes null :(

Comment: But you're not posting by submitting, you are using, ajax, isn't it? Why you're needing the action there? Probably that's why it's redirecting, maybe, somewhere in the code is submiting

Comment: Something tells me that this is not the code that is causing the issue. It is not possible to redirect via an ajax call, and this code you have posted is never submitting the form. Check other places in your code for the form being submitted, it's probably happening at the same time as your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have other issues within your code. Since this is a change listener, it isn't automatically submitting. Something else is causing the redirect to happen. You would need to paste the response that you are getting (302?) and debug from there.

Additionally, remove the action in the form tag to see if it is still submitting, but it's better to provide a fallback if your application can work without javascript.

Comment: This is exactly the issue, but until OP delivers, we can't do much else =\

Answer (score -1):

Your form action is being executed by default. You would need to stop the form from being submitted by using e.preventDefault();

When the change event occurs the next method takes hold and processes.

From the URL path I want to assume this is ASP.NET (Maybe) which by then the form action processing is going to do a postback.

Comment: I don't believe it is. Doing a e.preventDefault() on this event will not do anything to the form because if you look carefully, it's not an event on the form. It's the event handler for the <input type="file"/>. File inputs do not automatically submit the form (for obvious security reasons)

Comment: @mhodges can you explain why then? I mean if I'm going to get downvoted for this, can someone at least answer the question then?

Comment: I answered it in the comments on the post. The issue has to do with code that is not provided here. We cannot provide an answer for code we have yet to see. OP needs to dig deeper and help us out in order for us to solve the problem, but I promise you it has nothing to do with e.preventDefault() (at least in the code he provided - preventDefault() may need to be placed somewhere else in his code, but we need more info to find out where)